# Function is being exported as a blank object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module.exports

I am trying to export a function, called start, from one file. When I require it into the other file, I am getting "start is not a function" when I instantiate it.

I've tried making it a synchronous function, to no avail.

app.js:

```
const start = async () => {
  await init();
  inquirer
    .prompt([
      {
        type: 'list',
        name: 'startmenu',
        message: 'Choose one: ',
        choices: ['Login', 'Register']
      }
    ])
      .then((answer) => {
        if (answer.startmenu === 'Login') {
          return login();
        } else {
          return register();
        };
    });
};

module.exports = start;
```

playGame.js:

```
const start = require('../app');

const logOut = () => {
  return start();
}
```

Error I'm getting:

```
(node:47030) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: start is not a function
    at logOut (/Users/rjshoemaker/Desktop/code/projects/terminalscape/gamefiles/playGame.js:169:10)
    at inquirer.prompt.then (/Users/rjshoemaker/Desktop/code/projects/terminalscape/gamefiles/playGame.js:86:20)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
```

Comment: in `app.js` ... where is `start` even defined before it's exported? ... how can the first line of `app.js` even be `await init();` - that just will not work with javascript

Comment: Looks like you're missing the top of `App.js` maybe?

Comment: Sorry guys, I edited the question. Also, I shorted the files to only the parts in question.

Comment: start is a promise. you cant call it

Comment: @traktor53 thank you for the response. Can you explain what you mean or how I can fix it?

Comment: @traktor53 It's an async function, which means calling it returns a promise.

Comment: I was wrong - calling `start` returns a promise because it is an asynchronous function. However the code inside `start` doesn't return any value from the function - did you mean to return the promise chain result? Also, have you added a `catch` clause to the `start` promise anywhere?

Comment: @Barmar, got it - I was typing a correction but you beat me to it!

Comment: What does `console.log(start)` show?

Comment: @Barmar when I call it within the ```app.js``` file it works fine. what is the workaround for this?

Comment: @traktor53 None of that seems to be relevant to why he gets the error "start is not a function". If he can't even call the function, it doesn't matter what it does.

Comment: @Barmar inside of ```app.js``` it shows the function. However inside of ```playGame.js``` it just shows ```()```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `require('../App.js')`? You have the capitalization wrong.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, another typo on my part. The filename is ```app.js```

Comment: I still suspect you're not importing from the file you think you are.

Comment: Did you mean `{}` when you wrote `()`?

Comment: @Barmar yes, my bad

Comment: I don't understand how you can end up with that stack trace given those two source files.

Comment: Could you post a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how to reproduce the error? (My efforts to replace missing functions with dummy ones only produced working code.)